# Screen turns off and computer locks when playing flash video

Tags: 16.04, flash, lock-screen, video-streaming

> **OS**: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
>
> **Kernel**: 4.6.2-040602-generic #201606100516, x86_64
>
> **Browser**: Firefox 48 64-bit (Build ID 20160728203720)
>
> **Flash Plugin**: Shockwave Flash 11.2 r202

So I have my Brightness & Lock options set to turn the screen off after 3 minutes to save battery. But every time I play a flash video in either Firefox or Chrome (in full screen), the screen turns off after three minutes, and the laptop locks itself.

Apparently, this is a common issue with Flash on Ubuntu, no matter which version of Ubuntu you're running. There are some solutions to this issue, which I've tried. I've tried running this script (sudo and non-sudo) from ~/bin:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Cleanup any bad state we left behind if the user exited while flash was
# running
gconftool-2 -s /apps/gnome-screensaver/idle_activation_enabled --type bool true

we_turned_it_off=0

while true; do
    sleep 60
    flash_on=0

    for pid in `pgrep firefox` ; do
        if grep libflashplayer /proc/$pid/maps > /dev/null ; then
            flash_on=1
        fi

        ss_on=`gconftool-2 -g /apps/gnome-screensaver/idle_activation_enabled`

        if [ "$flash_on" = "1" ] && [ "$ss_on" = "true" ]; then
            gconftool-2 -s /apps/gnome-screensaver/idle_activation_enabled \
                --type bool false
            we_turned_it_off=1
        elif [ "$flash_on" = "0" ] && [ "$ss_on" = "false" ] \
                && [ "$we_turned_it_off" = "1" ]; then
            gconftool-2 -s /apps/gnome-screensaver/idle_activation_enabled \
                --type bool true
            we_turned_it_off=0
        fi

    done
done
```

But it doesn't seem to have an effect on Ubuntu 16.04. It does nothing.

The other solution proposed is Caffeine for Ubuntu. Caffeine works in 16.04, but it completely removes the screen off functionality. And on top of that, there's no 'Preferences' menu in version 2.8.3-3build1, which I have installed--so I can't set it to only work with a specific program, like Firefox.

Essentially, there's no way to automatically force the screen to continue running when a flash video is running in full screen, **and** to retain screen off functionality at the same time. I have to do it manually each time, by turning Caffeine on and off, or by disabling the screen off functionality from Brightness & Lock before I play the flash video, and to re-enable it when I'm finished.

I've got to wonder--why is this still a thing? This has been an issue on Ubuntu since 2012. It seems like a very obvious issue to solve but it's still unresolved. I find it strange.

Any other possible fixes for this on 16.04? Is there no way to get screen off functionality to recognize flash videos, or vice versa? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Caffeine 2.5 fixes this issue somewhat. I installed the .deb file and required packages, and it's functioning normally--it gives me a 'Preferences' menu that allows me to select programs like Firefox for automatic activation.

However, this means that my screen won't turn off if any instance of Firefox is active. So this is not a solution in itself. A proper, permanent solution would be to make it so that the screen-off feature doesn't interfere with full screen flash videos at all--like it is in Windows. I don't want to have to rely on Caffeine for this all the time.

Maybe downgrading to a much earlier Caffeine version will help with that. I know that older versions of the program are much more advanced--they include the option to only keep the screen on when videos are playing. However, such options are absent from all new (2.5+) versions of Caffeine, for some extremely odd reason. I have no idea why this is. For now, I may try downgrading to an old Caffeine version where the option to enable it for videos is present.

**EDIT**: I tested Caffeine 2.4.1. It does a much better job than Caffeine 2.5, in that it allows the screen to turn off even when Firefox is open, but stops the screen from turning off when a flash video is playing in full screen.

**However**, Caffeine 2.4.1 **allows the lock screen** to interfere with videos. So the screen doesn't turn to black when a flash video is playing in full screen, but if you have the lock screen enabled when the screen turns off, then the lock screen shows after X minutes, and you have to unlock the screen to keep watching the video.

Looks like there's no perfect solution to this issue. I have to keep the automatic lock screen functionality turned off just so that it doesn't interfere with full screen flash videos--I'll have to remember to manually lock my laptop every time I leave it alone now. Caffeine 2.2 and older produce the same results as Caffeine 2.4.1. The lock screen issue persists.

Caffeine (and this entire situation) is so weird. I wonder why the developer decided to cripple Caffeine's functionality in its newer iterations. Some kind of social experiment?